# C#.Net :How to read data on web api posted using curl

Tags: c#, curl

How to read data "user_token" in WebAPI posted using curl command.

**curl.exe "https://ssl.check.allin.net/api/Authenication" -d "user_token=3ff8c483-6c10-446d-a7b2-595b9d573d1f,content-length:1025" -v POST**

I'm not able to find "user_token" in postdata, headers, querystring. How to access data posted   . Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: It sends this via POST as you can read [in documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: How to access that posted Http Post Data on server?.

Comment: You wrote _"I'm not able to find "user_token" in postdata, headers, querystring."_ so this is another type of question which already has answer on SO.